# MS Access - Outer Join ON condition not behaving

Tags: ms-access, join, outer-join

I'm working with a query that does a simple outer join on 2 tables.  Originally, the join is coded:

```
FROM [T1]
LEFT JOIN [T2] 
ON   [T1].[Bank Account #] = [T2].Account)
AND [T1].[Payment Reference] = [T2].[Reference #]
```

Simple enough.  Until the "Reference" numbers started overlapping.  Easiest solution is to code the join ONLY when the `T1."payment dt" is <= T2."cashed date"`

I have a ref# 222456 with a "cashed date" of 1/1/2011.
I have a new row w/ 222456 (different types, and numbers now overlapping.  Type not available to match) with a payment date of 1/1/2016

To complicate matters, T1's Check date field is text, T2 is a date/time.

If I add this line:

```
and (Format(cDate([T1].[Payment Date]),'YYYYMMDD')
```

It DROPS the T1 row altogether.

I test the condition in the select, and it looks to be functioning as it should.

Where this condition is TRUE - I get appropriately matched T2 data

Where this condition is FALSE - and NO T2 record exists - I get just the T1 rec.

Where this condition is FALSE - but there is an existing T2 row where the first 2 fields match (but the date check fails) - then I get NO row returned at all.

I need T1 to return as if a T2 match is not found (which the ON should indicate)

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the design of the tables altogether and add a unique (identity) key, and then add a foreign key constrains? Dates can be quite tricky (they don't always adhere to the same format DD/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: I'm not sure of my ability to change. There's obviously design issues here, but this is what I have to work with.  This is bank reconciliation, so the bank piece would be the hard one to get changed.  It kinda is what it is.

I might be able to do something instead of a join query to create a combined table, just do an insert/update?  Should give me more control.

Comment: Maybe try to create a table which would consist of parts of the data, and then add that table to the join? Get the account and payment references and the data in one table, and the join that into the main table with the data, formatted correctly?